# Symfony 6 - How to measure requests flow in a Symfony project

Tags: symfony, request, action, measurement

I would like to know if it is possible to measure the flow of any kind of requests (such as Google requests, Firebase Cloud Messaging requests, third-party requests, etc...) sent when triggering an action (such as confirming a customer's order) in a Symfony project. If so, what tools should I use for that purpose? Any idea?

Comment: Check out https://www.blackfire.io/.